# Using Ruby if clause at end of assignment

Tags: ruby

Will `type` be set to `"foo"` if it `nil?`? Don't I need to write my own `nil?` function?

```
type = "foo" if type.nil?
```

Comment: yes `type` be set to `"foo"` if it not assigned any value before. Haven't you tried this and check?

Comment: Why do you think that you have to implement your own `nil?` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.nil?` returns a boolean, so you won't need to make that method.

If `type` is undefined or nil, `type` will == `"foo"` in your example code

Answer (score 2):

Yes, type will set to "foo" , if foo is null in your application.

You can also use the below for achieving the same functionality.

```
type ||= "foo"
```

If type = nil , then it will set to "foo" otherwise it will retain its value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `type` will get set to `"foo"` when its initially `nil`, by your code. Also, yes, you can avoid using `.nil?` by using `!type` instead.

However I would have written it like (assuming `type` will also get assigned when `false`):

```
type ||= "foo" 
#=> "foo"
```

Comment: just a reminder that `!type` is not a substitute for `type.nil?`.  if `type` is an empty string, `!type` will return `false`.

Comment: @jvnill if `type` is an empty string, `type.nil?` will also return `false`.

Comment: ah that's right.  i don't know what I was thinking earlier.  I guess I got used to using `.blank?` instead of `.nil?` so it will also check empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't I need to write my own `nil?` function?

No. `nil?` is implemented in two classes:

- [`Object#nil?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F) returns `false`
- [`NilClass#nil?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/NilClass.html#method-i-nil-3F) returns `true`

In other words: only `nil.nil?` is `true`, all other objects<sup>1</sup> respond with `false`.

> Will `type` be set to `"foo"` if it [responds `true` to] `nil?`?

Yes, exactly: `"foo"` is assigned to `type` if `type` is `nil`<sup>2</sup>. Otherwise, `type` remains unchanged.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is an exception though: instances of [`BasicObject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/BasicObject.html) don't respond to `nil?` but it's unlikely that you have to deal with them.

<sup>2</sup> `type` will also be `nil` if it is undefined. This is because Ruby then implicitly creates a new local variable `type` (with a value of `nil`) *before* calling `type.nil?`.